# grafana: Alerting when sum of values in a day is less than half the sum from the day one week ago

Tags: alert, grafana

I have a metric `foo.bar` that is incremented (+1) many times a day. The number of times the metric is incremented across a day is `x`. I want to detect whether there is something terribly wrong by alerting when `x` on the most recent full 24 hour period is less than half of `x`* from the same weekday 7 days prior.

What alert can I use for this?

Comment: What Grafana data source is your metric stored in? The query will likely be different depending on the data source.

Comment: data source is graphite

Answer (score 3):

You could try alerting on something like:

`divideSeries(hitcount(foo.bar,"1day"),hitcount(timeShift(foo.bar, "7d"), "1day"))`

And set an alert to fire if that value drops below 0.5. That will work best, I think, if you run the alert in a Grafana view with a time window some amount shorter than 1 day (this is a dim hunch, so take it with a grain).

If `hitcount` doesn't process the data correctly, you could use `integral` (or some `foo.bar.total` value if you have aggregation set up in Graphite itself). If you use `integral`, though, beware the accuracy-related pitfalls discussed in [this article](http://code.hootsuite.com/accurate-counting-with-graphite-and-statsd/). That writeup also discusses using `integral(hitcount(...))`, but since `hitcount` already aggregates, I don't think that will meet your use case. I may be wrong though.